# Table layout using percentages

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table in HTML with this structure:

[image: Table layout]

The contents will then to fit the cells.

I'm having trouble working out exactly what sizes need to be set to what to get this to work. The white space can be cellspacing or padding or anything else that works, but I can't work out what percentage to set it to. I'm more concerned about width than height, here, but the vertical and horizontal spacing should be equal in absolute terms.

For instance, if I wanted it more simply to be 10% - 10% - 80%, setting the spacing to 10% doesn't seem to create this.

Comment: Ya everything looks good, did you tried it first?

Comment: I've tried lots of ways to set this up, but none have worked quite how I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="border:1px solid black;width:100%">
     <tr><td >ffff</td><td rowspan="2" style="border:1px solid black">hhhhh</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="border:1px solid black">rrrr</td></tr>
    </table>
```

your this table  structure  for this

Comment: I don't want borders, and the issue isn't creating the structure but getting the widths exactly right, which you haven't addressed here.

Comment: so you can user div  easily  because  in table  you need to defile separate css for every td and percentage not work properly because it work according to content

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/ZhF7H/1/)**

```
  <table cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0"    width="100%" height="100%" style='background:red;'>
      <tbody>
      <tr >
        <td  style="width: 71.2%;
height: 49.55%; border-bottom: 4px solid white">
          Insert header image
        </td>
        <td   rowspan="2" style="height: 49.55%; width: 27.62%; border-left: 4px solid white;">
          Insert header image
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Insert header image
        </td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good except that I want the spacing to resize as well as the cells - hence why I wanted them all defined by %ages, so something like `cellspacing="0.46%"`

Comment: According to this you can:http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-cellspacing-attribute.php

Comment: Yes,we can give percentage value..Thanks for updating